# Trying to endgame upon reaching certain score in swift/Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

am very new to programming and trying to make a score counter app for a game I frequently play with my friends. I have all the buttons needed to correctly add up score but am trying to have game and upon one team reaching score of 11 points. Have tried using my basic knowledge of functions and if statements as well as searching on YouTube but have not yet found an answer. My code is very basic as I find it is much easier to use storyboards to generate an interface. Here is a piece of my code, goal is to make message with "game over" appear when ScoreOne = 11. Thanks again

```
 @IBAction func Point1(_ sender: Any) {
    
    ScoreOne = ScoreOne + 1
    
    Score1.text = "\(ScoreOne)"
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this. One simple way is to create a alert controller to show user the game is finished. Write below method showGameOverAlert(),
here you can set texts according to your will.

```
func showGameOverAlert() {
    let gameOverAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Game Over !!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    gameOverAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:{ _ in
            // do tasks when user pressed OK button
        }
    ))
    self.present(gameOverAlert, animated: true)
}
```

then call this method when score is 11

```
if ScoreOne == 11{
    self.showGameOverAlert()
}
```

Another way is, you can use UILabel to show user that game is over.
Suppose, you have a UILabel named scoreLabel in your storyborad or XIB file.
Create reference to your viewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel : UILabel!
```

In your viewDidLoad() method of your ViewController you can hide this label as you don't want to show this before the game is over. To hide this inside viewDidload() add :

```
scoreLabel.isHidden = true
```

then when your score is 11 show the label with text:

```
if ScoreOne == 11{
    scoreLabel.text = "Game Over !!"
    scoreLabel.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: with the second method you gave me when I put the if statement outside of viewDidLoad  I get an error claiming expected declaration even though I already declared ScoreOne as a variable, I also tried putting it inside viewDidLoad which doesn't create any errors but also doesn't display any messages.

Comment: you can write if statement inside func Point1 method where you increament the ScoreOne

Comment: I used "Winner" instead of scoreLabel and have Winner.isHidden = true in my viewDidLoad. Here is code simply in my view controller class function

Comment: if ScoreOne == 11{  // have "expected declaration" error here
        Winner.text = "Game Over !!"
        Winner.isHidden = false
    }

Comment: if ScoreOne == 11 ,,, inside which method you wrote this code? this should be added inside @IBAction func Point1(_ sender: Any) this method after ScoreOne = ScoreOne + 1 this line

Comment: @HenryDyer if my answer solve your problem then select it as correct answer